# Open DIV at mouse click - not appear out of screen

Tags: jquery

I have a problem once again, I'm trying to open a DIV at the mouse location. At the project I'm working on this is to open a custom made dialog. Now, I made it possible to open the DIV at mouse position. But I got a few problems:

- Sometimes the DIV appears out of the container
- Whenever firebug is opened (don't know about other developer tool windows), the dialog will be partly behind firebug.

Now, I got this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="dialog">
      Some content in here...
    </div>

    <a class="first-link">Open first link</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.first-link').unbind('click').click(openDialog);
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  window.mouseX = e.pageX;
  window.mouseY = e.pageY;
});

function openDialog(e) {
  var elem = $('<div class="dialog">hello</div>')
  $('.content').append(elem);

  var x = window.mouseX;
  var y = window.mouseY;

  var windowWidth = $('.content').width();
  var windowHeight = $('.content').height();

  var dialogWidth = $(elem).width();
  var dialogHeight = $(elem).height();

  var calc = windowWidth - (x + dialogWidth);

  if (calc < 0)
  {
    x += calc - 10;
  }

 calc = windowHeight - (y + dialogHeight);

  if (calc < 0)
  {
    y += calc - 20;
  }

  elem.draggable({containment: '.content'});
  elem.css('position', 'absolute').css('top', y).css('left', x);
}
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  height: 500px;
}

.content
{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
}

.dialog
{
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

.first-link
{
  position: relative;
  top: 160px;
  left: 5px;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshB1997/qbn0zu8r/5/

I don't know whether my way of doing the calculation is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you complicating yourself? Can I give you a simple way? Use the CSS to calculate the centering of the dialog. Concentrate on HTML manipulations:

```
$(function() {
  $(".first-link").click(function() {
        $(".content").append('<div class="new-dialog">Hello!</div>');
  });
});

.new-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w04g2dov/**

Comment: I don't need it to appear in the center of the content, but at the mouse position.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker Should it move with the mouse?

Comment: No. Basically, I just need it to open at the mouse location, but it should never get out of the screen or below firebug (but it should be closest to the mouse position). The movement is done by jQuery draggable.